# Azure B2C: Microsoft Graph API - InvalidAuthenticationToken

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to call `/me` on the Microsoft Graph API after logging into an Azure B2C Active Directory from iOS.

Using the sample application at: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msa I've replaced the constants such that sign-up and sign-in work. I've set the `kGraphURI` to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. The code looks like this:

```
let kTenantName = "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"
let kAuthorityHostName = "mytenant.b2clogin.com"
let kClientID = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
let kSignupOrSigninPolicy = "B2C_1A_signup_signin"
let kGraphURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
let kScopes: [String] = ["https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation"]
```

The value for `kScopes` is set to the only API my application has available, which was created as part of the instructions for setting up user policies.

When I try to call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` I get back:

> {   "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
>       "message": "Access token validation failure.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "e923673f-25cb-44be-b3b9-94eda660d4f6",
>         "date": "2020-02-11T08:31:24"
>       }   } }

If I try to set `kScopes` to `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read` I get an error:

> Could not acquire token: Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50000
>   "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Authentication response
>   received without expected accessToken,
>   MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42008,
>   MSALCorrelationIDKey=FFCCD1D4-F0C8-46E6-85B2-A5642F1D4E1D}

How do I call the `/me` Microsoft Graph API with an access token from Azure B2C Active Directory?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to get an access token for Microsoft Graph  via a B2C user authenticated against the B2C endpoints? It's impossible. Graph api should be accessed via AAD auth endpoint. So you can get the access token for custom web api rather than Microsoft Graph.

Comment: you got any answer? because i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the Azure AD B2C issued access tokens to call Azure AD or Microsoft Graph API. You must have the user call your API, and your API needs to use client_credentials to obtain a token for Graph API using the Azure AD token endpoint of your B2C directory. Then the API can query Graph API for the user and return the result.

Azure AD B2C access tokens can only be used to access your own protected resources.

Comment: Is there an example or some documentation that explains how this works? That seems incredibly counter-intuitive!

Comment: B2C calling a Web API you own: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=applications

AAD calling MS Graph API as a daemon app (client credentials)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon

For users, the usual way to access their profile is via the Profile Edit functionality. Everything else should be in the id_token.

Comment: If I understand correctly, B2C calling a Web API is passing the B2C access_token and the web API is then responsible for validating the token and checking all the permissions / claims. If so, it isn't really clear what value AAD B2C brings. I feel like I must be missing something obvious!
The second sample then uses application permissions instead of delegated permissions to call the Graph API?

Comment: For example if it’s your own e-commerce website which your customers need to sign up to, go and use AAD B2C. It is not for accessing Azure services with end user context. AAD cannot do a self service sign up or fully custom authentication flows but can allow obtaining a token to use against Graph API or other Microsoft API. What’s not clear from your post is why you would need to allow a user to call Graph API in the first place? Yes your understanding is correct otherwise.

Comment: I'd like users to be able to sign up themselves. Eventually I want to place them in a Group and be able to integrate with Microsoft Teams for a chat service, hence the need for Graph API integration. So if I'm signing up users with B2C, I need to build an API that validates a B2C `access_token`, then use a `client_credential` (i.e. application not delegated) token to make Microsoft Graph API calls on behalf of the user?

Comment: Unfortunately, that crossing of boundary, where there is consumer sign up, and access to O365 is something that is not easily implemented right now. Something we are looking into heavily. Yes your understanding is right. The users would need to be abstracted from the entire set of Microsoft services being used, by a middleman API that orchestrates their commands. Group assignment is available though.

Comment: I don't get it, why would you not allow a backend to make calls with the user's access token? Isn't that the entire point of OAuth? Why is there an OAuth consent screen, showing me what access I'm handing out to the application, if the application doesn't actually get that access?

Comment: @Tim I was scratching my head for a couple of days with the exact same question. Why would you not allow calling the Graph API with AAD-B2C token? I think the argument of "a user should not be able to call Graph API with an access token is invalid because you can do that with AD token". Anyway after a lot of digging and ending up in this question, it seems that there is no way to do this rather than validating the access token and calling the Graph API in the backend which feels like bad design. Its just the Azure does not support it - bad design from their end